# Basic NPM, Gulp Setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I'm attempting automate my front-end development, so I started by pulling in dependencies with NPM. My `package.json` looks like:

```
"main": "main.js",
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^2.1.4",
  "vue": "^0.12.8"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
  "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0"
}
```

My `gulpfile.json` looks like:

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    sass       = require('gulp-sass'),
    minify_css = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    notify     = require('gulp-notify'),
    autoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify     = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename     = require('gulp-rename');

var src = {
    sass: 'assets/sass/',
    js: 'assets/js/',
};

var output = {
    css: 'public/css/',
    js: 'public/js/',
};

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(src.sass + 'main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefix('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(minify_css())
        .pipe(rename({basename: 'styles'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output.css))
        .pipe(notify('CSS processed.'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src([
            src.js + 'main.js',
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output.js))
        .pipe(notify('JS processed.'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    browserSync.init({server: './output'});
    gulp.watch(src.sass + '**/*.scss', ['css']);
    gulp.watch(src.js + '**/*.js', ['js']);
    gulp.watch(src.js + '**/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'watch']);
```

It works! Great!

I want to start writing code in `main.js`, but **where I'm stuck is figuring out how to `require` jQuery and Vue (and whatever else) into my `main.js` file**.

(Edit: It doesn't necessarily have to be done in the `main.js` file, I just want the end result to be that I can write code as expected and minify it. It appears that I can't `require('jquery')` inside the gulp js task, but perhaps I'm going about it incorrectly.)

Comment: Are you running in a node environment? Or just using node in your build process?

Comment: I'm just using node in the build process.

Comment: Sounds like Webpack / Browserify will give you what you are looking for

Comment: @urish He wants to use Browserify, but doesn't have the appropriate task set up. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only using node for your build/workflow, you're not going to be calling Node's exports (hopefully) in your application code. So the short answer is, however you were doing it before.

Edit: I see you've tagged the question with browserify. If you're trying to require with browserify, then what you need to do is have a gulp task run the browserify command, which will then take care of your dependencies. Node's require, which is what you are currently calling in your gulpfile, is a different animal. It's used to ensure you have all the packages you need, but you need to run browserify so your requires in your app code will work.